# get <apex:input> value on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I have created a datepicker inside the visualforce page using `<apex:input>` and I want to get value of that `<apex:input>` into a variable. After little bit bit of googling , I found that create a `{get;set;}` variable inside the controller apex class and use that varible as `value` field of the `<apex:input>`. So, here's the code:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" 
               controller="ShowResourcesClass" >

         <apex:form >
                <apex:pageBlock >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                                 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
                                Date: <apex:input type="date" value="{!chosenDate}"/>
                             </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>

            <apex:form >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!getDateFun}" value="Submit" id="theButton"/>
            </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

And this is the controller class:

```
public class ShowResourcesClass {

public Date chosenDate {get;set;}

public void getDateFun() {
    System.debug('DATE: ' + chosenDate);
 }
}
```

After I choose the date and click the submit button, the value of `chosenDate` is null. I cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above mentioned visualforce page, the `<apex:commandButton>` and `<apex:input>` are in different `<apex:form>`s. Thats the reason why I wasn't getting the value of  `dateChosen`. I got the value when I put both the buttons in the same form. ie,

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" 
           controller="ShowResourcesClass" >

     <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                             <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
                            Date: <apex:input type="date" value="{!chosenDate}"/>
                         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>

            <apex:commandButton action="{!getDateFun}" value="Submit" id="theButton"/>

        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```